# React Native : Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I am writing jest test case for a particular file, the file has NativeModule import in it.

While running the test case, I am getting the following error:

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

    Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument.

      at invariant (node_modules/invariant/invariant.js:40:15)
      at new NativeEventEmitter (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter.js:45:7)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-quantum-metric-library/index.js:1:322)
```

After googling the above error, I did few changes by adding the following code inside the test file.

```
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter');
```

After adding the above line then I got the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'eventType')

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-quantum-metric-library/index.js:1:367)
```

After googling again, I modified the above code with the following code.

```
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter.js', () => {
  const {EventEmitter} = require('events');
  return EventEmitter;
});
```

After above modification I am getting the below error.

```
● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: _reactNative.NativeEventEmitter is not a constructor

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native-quantum-metric-library/index.js:1:322)
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve the above issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock `react-native-fs` in your unit test case file to solve dependency issue.

```
jest.mock('react-native-fs', () => {
 return {
  mkdir: jest.fn(),
  moveFile: jest.fn(),
  copyFile: jest.fn(),
  pathForBundle: jest.fn(),
  pathForGroup: jest.fn(),
  getFSInfo: jest.fn(),
  getAllExternalFilesDirs: jest.fn(),
  unlink: jest.fn(),
  exists: jest.fn(),
  stopDownload: jest.fn(),
  resumeDownload: jest.fn(),
  isResumable: jest.fn(),
  stopUpload: jest.fn(),
  completeHandlerIOS: jest.fn(),
  readDir: jest.fn(),
  readDirAssets: jest.fn(),
  existsAssets: jest.fn(),
  readdir: jest.fn(),
  setReadable: jest.fn(),
  stat: jest.fn(),
  readFile: jest.fn(),
  read: jest.fn(),
  readFileAssets: jest.fn(),
  hash: jest.fn(),
  copyFileAssets: jest.fn(),
  copyFileAssetsIOS: jest.fn(),
  copyAssetsVideoIOS: jest.fn(),
  writeFile: jest.fn(),
  appendFile: jest.fn(),
  write: jest.fn(),
  downloadFile: jest.fn(),
  uploadFiles: jest.fn(),
  touch: jest.fn(),
  MainBundlePath: jest.fn(),
  CachesDirectoryPath: jest.fn(),
  DocumentDirectoryPath: jest.fn(),
  ExternalDirectoryPath: jest.fn(),
  ExternalStorageDirectoryPath: jest.fn(),
  TemporaryDirectoryPath: jest.fn(),
  LibraryDirectoryPath: jest.fn(),
  PicturesDirectoryPath: jest.fn()
 }
})
```